# in linq to entities, how to do an inner EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM... type of query?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-ctp5, vb.net-2010

I am trying to write a LINQ equivalent of

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3
FROM T1
WHERE T1.C4='xyz' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2
             WHERE T1.C17 = T2.C24)
ORDER BY C3
```

I'm using EF CTP 5, so I have a DBContext variable named dbc, which includes DBSet objects T1s and T2s, based on POCOs T1 and T2.

In LINQ I write

```
DIM IND = From i In dbc.T1s
          Where i.C4 = "xyz" 
          And (From t In dbc.T2s Where i.C17 = t.C24).Any
          Select i.C1, i.C2, i.C3
          Order By C3
```

Running the query I get the error message "Unable to create a constant value of type 'T2'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

When I omit the inner expression (third line in the LINQ code), the query runs fine.

I tried switching the orders of the inner comparison, to be t.C24 = i.C17, with no effect.

So what is going on, and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query to use LINQ to SQL such that dbc is a DataContext object, and all is fine.  Seems LINQ to Entities is still (even in .Net 4) quite limited.